# How to create a session object in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am integrating Facebook and Twiiter api in my application. Api is integrated well. Now, I want to store username of both in session.

How will I create or declare session in objective-c application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ray has posted a great tutorial about this, you must visit that link first.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

Comment: @sayed.. I am asking, how I will have to declare or create session in my application? I am not asking to integrate facebook in application.

Answer (score 0):

Since iPhone Apps are single user, you don't need sessions at all. When you want to save data in some way, you could just use a variable. If you want the data to be persistent, you could use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).